# Realtime decoding - stdin to stdout

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg

I am searching for a possibility to pass encoded audio data to a ffmpeg process (using stdin) and retrieve the decoded audio data (using stdout). 
I tried to find the necessary arguments for the ffmpeg process but I could not find any. Is there really no such possibility? 
Again: I would like to decode data in realtime (for example during a playback).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i - -f s16le -
```

Will decode input file - (stdin) and pass it to output file - (stdout) as format 16-bit integer in little endian PCM format (-f s16le).